# How to make an external GET request from IIS hosted WebAPI/MVC app (via proxy server)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, credentials

We use **Windows authentication**. I've created both **WebAPI**/**MVC** applications to play with.

When hosted on **production server** / **IIS** appplication requires credentials to perform **HTTP GET** to an external site. For some reasons we temporarily cannot use special **AD account** for that.

I've read about **ASP.NET impersonation**. As far as I understand it is possible to incorporate with caller's credentials? I've tried to use this code though I'm not sure whether it is an appropriate approach to use with **WebAPI**.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/test")]
public HttpResponseMessage test() {
    using(var ctx = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate()) {
        var proxyOptions = new WebProxy("[proxyUrl]");
            proxyOptions.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        var client = new WebClient();
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;                
            client.Proxy = proxyOptions;

        return new HttpResponseMessage {
            Content = new StringContent(
                content: client.DownloadString("[externalApiUrl]"),
                encoding: Encoding.Default,
                mediaType: "text/plain"
            )
        };
    }
}
```

Anyway this doesn't work.

Should I configure *delegation* instead of *impersonation*?

How to perform an external request without a separate **AD** account for that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly setting the credentials using

```
var proxyConfig = new WebProxy(
proxyServerUrl, 
BypassOnLocal: false, 
BypassList: null, 
Credentials: new NetworkCredential(username, password)
);
```

The username / password should be an authorized user on your proxy server. Since you are using Windows Authentication, you may need to prefix domain name in the username E.g. domain\username

This approach should work in all the 3 environments you have mentioned.

Comment: Yes, this is truly the simplest way of doing this. But we might not have an account dedicated for that purpose.

Comment: Have you tried CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials instead of DefaultNetworkCredentials